# Find all positive integers $x,y$ such that $(x+y)(xy+1)$ is a power of $2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, perfect-powers, parity

Find all positive integers $x,y$ such that $(x+y)(xy+1)$ is a power of $2$

It is clear that as we are given a factorisation of the power of two, both of those terms have to be powers of two. $x+y$ is then even and $xy$ is odd, which only happens when both $x,y$ are odd.

Then some obvious solutions include $x,y = \left\{ 1,1 \right\},\left\{ 1,3 \right\},\left\{ 1,7 \right\},...$

I am not sure how to proced with finding the complete set (and proving its completeness). Perhaps examination modulo some other integer? I have not been successful with $3$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Off the top of my head, there's also a family of solutions $(3, 5), (7, 9), (15, 17), (31, 33), \ldots$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elementary Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363313/elementary-diophantine-equation). Note this same question was also asked more recently at [Solve for positive integers $x,y,z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3402381/602049), but it's only answer is not a complete solution.

Comment: I just provide numerical solutions for $x,y\le10000$ (only cases $x<=y$):
(1, 1)
(1, 3)
(1, 7)
(1, 15)
(1, 31)
(1, 63)
(1, 127)
(1, 255)
(1, 511)
(1, 1023)
(1, 2047)
(1, 4095)
(1, 8191)
(3, 5)
(7, 9)
(15, 17)
(31, 33)
(63, 65)
(127, 129)
(255, 257)
(511, 513)
(1025, 3071)
(2049, 6143)
(3073, 5119)
(3615, 4641)
(6505, 8855)
(7049, 9639)
(7169, 9215)
(7681, 8703)
(7711, 8737)
(8703, 8705)

Comment: @VítězslavŠtembera fwiw : I don't think $(7049 + 9639) * (7049 * 9639 + 1) = 1133871366656$ for example is a power of 2

Comment: I think the solutions are pairs $(1,2^n-1)$ with $n>=1$ or pairs $(2^n-1,2^n+1)$ with $n>=2$ but I need to find a proof :-) In binary both the numbers end in $1$ and otherwise they complement.

Comment: actually pairs $(0,2^n)$ with $n \ge 0$ are fine as well (always assuming $x \le y$)